# Is w ∈ L(M ) ⟹ ww ∈ L(M) co-semi-decidable?

Tags: computability, semi-decidability

Consider the following langugage:

$\qquad L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid M \text{ TM}, w \in L(M) \implies ww \in L(M)\}$.

I've been asked to decide whether this language is in R/RE/CO-RE. I've proved that the language doesn't belong to R and RE using Rice theorem, but I can't find a formal proof for CO-RE. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried, specifically? Have you tried proving the oppoosite? (I assume the definition of $L$ uses "for all $w$" implicitly, i.e. $w$ is not fixed.)

Comment: L complement contains a least one w such that ww is not in L. I know few tools: rice theorem which won't work in this case since the empty langugae in not included in the complement. So it is either assuming that exists turing machine which recognizes this language and contradict it, or finding a reduction from non turing recognizable language to the complement. I couldn't find nothing in both ways.

Comment: You don't *need* the empty function for the [extended Rice theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice-Shapiro_theorem), even though it's often a convenient choice.

Comment: I didn't learned this theorm. I can't use it. The questions is from an assignment that I need to submit. Can you help me with a direction to the prove, using the tools I know (reductions, Rice theorem, assuming the negative and contradicting)?

Comment: Then please give a reference to the exact theorem you may use. Keep in mind that this is a Q&A portal, not a homework solving service.

Comment: Let P be a set of languages with some property. P is not trivial if P!=RE and P is not empty. For non trivial P we can say that L={TM M | L(M)∈P} is undecidable. If the empty languange belones to P, then P is non-turing recognizable. I don't ask you to solve my homework, just a minor help after I couldn't myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20400/discussion-between-user3680924-and-raphael).

Answer (score 3):

You can show that this language $L$ is not co-RE in the following way:

Assume $L$ was co-RE, that is you have a semi-algorithm $A$ to decide given an input machine $M$ whether there exists a word $w\in L(M)$ such that $ww\notin L(M)$.

We show that we can build a semi-algorithm to decide the complement of the halting problem (on empty input), which is impossible.

The algorithm goes like this, on input $M$:

1. Build a machine $M'$ that

   - simulates $M(\varepsilon)$ on input $00$ and accepts if $M$ halts,
   - accepts on input $0$,
   - and accepts on all other inputs.
2. Run algorithm $A$ on $M'$.

Now $A(M')$ will answer yes iff $M'$ accepts $0$ but rejects $00$, meaning iff $M$ does not halt on empty input. Hence we have constructed an algorithm that semi-decides the complement of the Halting problem, which is a contradiction (it is not possible).

Comment: Nice! Note that for some formulations of the (special) Halting problem, you want to use $\langle M \rangle$ instead of the empty input. Works just as well.

Comment: In step 1.3, did you mean `accept` on all other inputs?